# Данные из двух диапазонов собрать в одну таблицу

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как объединить столбцы? Пример на фото.

Имеются 8 столбцов. `A-H`. В итог попадает сначала `А2-D2`, следующей строкой `E2-H2`. Далее все по новой - `A3-D3`... Но если `E3-H3` пусто, то пропускается.

Как это всё организовать?

Заранее спасибо за помощь)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Самое простое решение - ввести два дополнительных столбца. В них считать строку и столбец следующего значения. В целевых ячейках делать выборку по посчитанным значениям.

Comment: @Akina да если бы я дружил с ехел формулами...А так вообще 0 в них (

Answer (score 1):

Задача усложнена тем, что данные в двух диапазонах и с возможными пропусками. Но формулами можно побаловаться.

Формулы написаны в `Excel`. Если нужно, адаптировать для *Google*-таблиц.
Результат для демонстрации примера размещен а том же листе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В доп. столбце `А` нумерация строк первого диапазона (в `А2` и протянуть):

```
=ЕСЛИ(B2="";;МАКС($A$1:A1;$F$1:F1)+1)
```

В доп. столбце `F` нумерация строк второго диапазона (в `F2` и протянуть):

```
=ЕСЛИ(G2="";;МАКС($A$1:A2)+1)
```

В доп. столбце `L` определение номера диапазона (в `L2` и протянуть):

```
=ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА(A1)>$L$1;;ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A:A;СТРОКА(A1));1;2))
```

В `L1` для облегчения вычислений - количество записей в двух диапазонах:

```
=МАКС(A2:A100;F2:F100)
```

Пронумеровать строки в столбце `M` можно вручную. можно формулой (в `M2` и протянуть):

```
=ЕСЛИ(L2;МАКС($M$1:M1)+1;)
```

Выбор значений осуществляется формулой (в `N2`, копировать на 4 столбца и протянуть):

```
=ЕСЛИ($M2;ВПР($M2;ИНДЕКС(($A:$E;$F:$J);;;$L2);СТОЛБЕЦ(B1););"")
```

Для уменьшения вычислений № столбца можно вписать константой: вместо `СТОЛБЕЦ(B1)` числа от 2 до 5.

Для столбца "*Кол-во*" текст нулевой длины лучше заменить на ноль:

```
=ЕСЛИ($M2;ВПР($M2;ИНДЕКС(($A:$E;$F:$J);;;$L2);4;);)
```